# Apply distortion on a custom Unity camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, matrix, camera, calibration, distortion

I'm trying to apply distortion on unity camera using Camera.worldToCameraMatrix. I can project a custom matrix on my camera but I think I'll should to project calculated and applied matrix for each pixel, like :

```
for x, y in tab:
    double xDistort = x * (1 + k1 * r2 + k2 * r2 * r2 + k3 * r2 * r2 * r2); 
    double yDistort = y * (1 + k1 * r2 + k2 * r2 * r2 + k3 * r2 * r2 * r2);
```

The problem is that I didn't find a way to apply my operation on my each pixels. It is possible to access and project matrix on each pixels or is it aberrant ? Maybe I should do it with shaders ?

Thank you.

Comment: This does indeed sound like a job for [writing a custom shader in the Post Processing framework](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/PostProcessing/wiki/Writing-Custom-Effects) (which you can add via the Package Manager). For instance, the [Lens Distortion filter](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/PostProcessing/wiki/Lens-Distortion) is using that. After installing the package you are able to find it in Library/PackageCache/com.unity.postprocessing@2.2.2/PostProcessing/Shaders/Builtins/Distortion.hlsl for some inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'll explore this pakage !